# Keeping rows that have different content in the first column but the same content in the last column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I think that my question title is very explanatory itself. So, I will represent below a pratical example with a original dataframe and the desired output.

Imagine that a have a dataframe just like this:

```
         Gene    VC     TSB
1        TP53   Sil      A
2        TTN    Mis      B
3        TTN    Mis      C
4        TP53   Sil      C
5        TTN    Sil      B
```

My desired output would be something like:

```
      Gene   VC    TSB
3     TTN    Mis    C
4     TP53   Sil    C
```

As you can see, I only keep index 3 and 4 since those were the only ones whos 1 column value were different but the third column value were the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is using `Series.duplicated()`. First create a mask that makes sure you don't include duplicates of both columns and then add a condition that the first column must be a duplicate:

```
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['tsb', 'gene'], keep=False)
target_df = df[~mask&df[~mask].duplicated(subset='tsb', keep=False)]
print(target_df)

   gene tsb
0  TP53   A
2   TTN   C
3  TP53   C
5   TTN   A
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `filter` with `groupby`

```
df.groupby('TSB').filter(lambda x : (x['Gene'].nunique()==len(x['Gene']))&(len(x['Gene'])>1))
Out[737]: 
   Gene   VC TSB
3   TTN  Mis   C
4  TP53  Sil   C
```

Comment: Works, thank you ! COuld you just pls take a look at the 2 extras that I add to the question ?

Comment: @JoãoFernandes just hangs the group by key to Gene and filter to TSB

Comment: @JoãoFernandes to tell the truth , edit the question after answer posted is not good .